# Implementing CUDA parallel processes with/without cudaStream* functions?

Tags: multithreading, process, cuda, parallel-processing

I refer to this thread [Creating a cuda stream on each host thread (multi-threaded CPU)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19387583/creating-a-cuda-stream-on-each-host-thread-multi-threaded-cpu) and also this example script from NVIDIA [simpleStreams.cu](http://www.naic.edu/~phil/hardware/nvidia/doc/src/simpleStreams/simpleStreams.cu).

I hope with this brief prolog you understand better the situation:

1. I calculate on a Quadro K5000 for a given time range all possible Elliott Waves which can be used for trading Forex, Futures or stocks. For 120 time bars there are more than 190 million combinations to calculate -> a perfect job for the GPU. (170 bars cause 1.1 billion combinations...)
2. The bar data [low & high] are delivered from the Trading Software NinjaTrader which are processed in my PHP engine and stored into a MySQL database.
3. The PHP engine starts periodically **for each** instrument (EURUSD, USDJPY, ...) **one instance** of the CUDA program via `exec()`. This means when we have 20 instruments to calculate there are 20 independent instances (no threads!) running on the SLES 11 server (20 lines in the output of `ps aux`)
4. Due to the fact the bar data is delivered for all instruments at the same time (end of each minute) there is always a peak!

My intention was to write a scheduler which queues the requests and starts one by one the calculation on the GPU with CUDA. Due to a bug the queue did not work for a short time and all instances of the calculation program were executed more or less simultaneously.

I have some integrity checks to assure the program is calculating correctly and after checking and testing it I realized - due to the output of my internal log - that the GPU processed all these requests parallel without any error.

***Now my questions:***

1. Why does it work without using the `cudaStream*` functions? Is it because the parallel tasks are not called from **one instance** of the CUDA program but from **different physical instances**? I have to avoid it is working accidentally (because I could not detect incorrect calculations with my tests) and the implementation is inconsistent and may/will fail for some tasks and therefore useless!
2. As I wrote my intention was to write a scheduler to queue the requests. This was planed to be a small C++ web server where the calculation requests would be processed by threads. Now for me is the question if I should leave it as it is because implementing it as a web server with one program instance with different threads I would have probably to use the `cudaStream*` functions and the whole implementation would be more complicated without any performance improvement. Now I would be "finished"...

*Just a notice*: The execution time calculating the set of instruments needs in the serialized version 54 seconds - the massive parallel version needs 19 seconds (65% faster).

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1.Why does it work without using the cudaStream* functions? Is it because the parallel tasks are not called from one instance of the CUDA program but from different physical instances?

Your launcher (exec()) is spawning a new process for each CUDA executable launched.  Assuming your GPU is in default compute mode, CUDA activity from separate processes will be serialized.  This means that while one process is using the GPU, no other processes will be, but they will peacefully coexist, and serialize and wait their turn.  Once a process releases the GPU, another process will start using it (creating a new context).

> 2.As I wrote my intention was to write a scheduler to queue the requests. This was planed to be a small C++ web server where the calculation requests would be processed by threads. Now for me is the question if I should leave it as it is...

This probably can't be answered concisely, except by you.  There may be some overall improvement in scheduling *rate* if you manage the work yourself from one or several threads of a single process - this could possibly avoid context destruction/creation etc.  Also, if your kernels are very small, you could possibly run multiple kernels simultaneously if they originate from a single process. This requires considerably more effort from the programmer to manage correctly.

Separately, CUDA Hyper-Q on cc 3.5 and newer devices, along with [CUDA MPS](https://docs.nvidia.com/deploy/pdf/CUDA_Multi_Process_Service_Overview.pdf) in a linux environment, can improve the utilization of a single GPU in some scenarios, allowing multiple processes to run their work simultaneously.  But if your individual jobs/kernels are fully utilizing the GPU, then this is not likely to give much additional benefit either.

Comment: @ *Assuming your GPU is in default compute mode, CUDA activity from separate processes will be serialized.*  When I implement it as a web server (your pointed out correctly with this I can avoid context desctruction/creation/memory allocation), can I just call in any thread the device function without taking care about any parallel issues because the CUDA kernel will serialize the requests for me or do I have to use the cudaStream* functions?

Comment: Requests coming from a single process (e.g. a single application, regardless of threads) will not be automatically serialized, and the programmer must make sure that the allocations (in particular) are done in such a fashion as to respect the GPU memory limitations.  The CUDA runtime will serialize CUDA API calls and kernel calls issued to a particular stream.  If no streams are used, all activity flows into the default stream and will be serialized.  However a poorly organized app, whether multi-threaded or not, could request more memory than is available on the GPU.

Comment: Thank you Robert. The memory limitation was the first I checked when I was designing the web server.